# SwipeRefreshLayout holds a fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I looked that if I open a new fragment [2] and my app enables the refreshing mode in the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and after I will return to previous fragment [1] pressing the back button (the refreshing mode works at this moment) then fragments will switch but on the screen I will see same fragment `View`, not current. Why my previous fragment [1] that I enable cannot draws on the screen and I see [2] fragment `View` although all `View` listeners of the previous fragment [1] work.

This bug appears only if `SwipeRefreshLayout`'s refreshing mode is enabled.

How to fix it? Or should I override on back press method for each fragment?