# Why Android doesn't call onDetachWindow method in a View?

Tags: android, android-view

I looked that Android doesn't call `onDetachWindow` method in a `View` sometimes and it's a reason of bug in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I described this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816233/swiperefreshlayout-holds-a-fragment-view).
Why it happens? And how to fix it?

P.S. It happens only when the user opens a new fragment and closes it quickly.